# Stack with type parameter error in C#

Tags: c#, .net, generics, stack

I am using **.NETFramework,Version=v4.5** and trying to create the following stack:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
...
Stack<int> s = new Stack<int>();
```

Why am I getting this error?

> Class 'System.Collections.Stack' does not
>   have type parameters

A stack without type parameter works fine.

Comment: Are you referencing `System.Collections` as well?

Comment: You can see from the error that it's using `System.Collections.Stack` and not the generic version, so @YuvalItzchakov is probably right.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Why would that be a problem?

Comment: Mine works fine using System.Collections.Generic, I dont believe the first comment is the issue.

Comment: Are you certain `Stack<int> s = new Stack<int>();` is where the exception is happening? If it is, can you just try changing it to:  `System.Collections.Generic.Stack<int> s = new System.Collections.Generic.Stack<int>();` ?

Comment: @JonH Exactly, hence why I asked why that would be an issue.

Comment: @DavidG - Shrug 4 other lost souls thought it was helpful without trying to check.  RTFM!

Comment: Looks like it was just modified, @henninghall ensure that you are `using System.Collections.Generic;` as well. `Stack<T>` belongs to the `System.Collections.Generic` namespace.

Comment: @JonH Now OP has changed the question and suddenly it becomes clear.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov yes I reference System.Collections. My bad to not include that line in the question. Now edited.

Comment: @DavidG - Well a simple read of the documentation on both classes sure goes a long way.  Now it makes perfect sense why the error.  henninghall get rid of that using statement and add using system.collections.generic.

Comment: @DavidG - I just find it weird the original question had the right using statement but the error was not valid for just that using statement.  Than it is edited to have the wrong using statement???!?!?! Is this a sock puppet?

Comment: @JonH check out the latest edit!

Comment: I am using all the imports in the 2nd edit of the question and still gets the same error.

Comment: @DavidG - This sounds fishy, or is a help vampire, or is simply a lost soul wasting our time.

Comment: @JonH Agreed, either way I have VC as typo

Comment: @henninghall - DONT use all the imports..use the generic one...OR specify the type with the namespace on the declaration.System.Collections.Generic.Stack<int> s = new System.Collections.Generic.Stack<int>();  In this way the compiler doesn't confuse the types due to ambiguity.

Comment: @henninghall - Maybe delete your `obj` directory and rebuild the solution. Also clear the output directory before.

Comment: @BendEg - With those using statements clearing anything will serve no purpose.

Comment: Having all of the using statements in there should not matter one bit as `Stack<T>` is a completely different class than `Stack` and could never get confused between `System.Collections` and `System.Collections.Generic`. Just as good practice, any time I see something weird, I will delete my `bin` and `obj` folders from each project in my solution before rebuilding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem by creating a new project from existing code.

Didn't need to change any code after that so still unsure about what caused the error.

Answer (score 5):

This works for me:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace HashSetPerformance
{
    public class SampleStack
    {
        public SampleStack()
        {
            Stack<int> s = new Stack<int>();
        }
    }
}
```

Just take a look at: [MSDN-Generic-Stack-Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/3278tedw(v=vs.110).aspx)

Be sure you are not doing this:

```
using System.Collections; // This has to be: using System.Collections.Generic;

    namespace HashSetPerformance
    {
        public class SampleStack
        {
            public SampleStack()
            {
                Stack<int> s = new Stack<int>();
            }
        }
    }
```

Because this uses the none generic type `Stack`-Class: [MSDN-Stack-Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.collections.stack(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Whats wrong with this answer?

Comment: Nothing but it started out awful.

Answer (score 2):

You are using the wrong import:

```
using System.Collections;
```

Should be:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the *generic* stack class - one that allows you to create a stack of ints - you need to use `System.Collections.Generic`.

`System.Collections` lets you create a stack of objects.

With the non-generic stack, you could shove the number 42 and the string "frotz" onto the stack like so:

```
s.Push(42);
s.Push("frotz");
```

But you've got to *know* (or figure out) what you've got when you pop something off that stack.  Because it handles everything as an `object`, not as an `int` or a `string`.

With the generic stack, you wouldn't push ints and strings onto it. You'd push ints *or* strings onto it based on how it was declared.

`Stack` is old-school like using `ArrayList` - it's just a collection of objects.

`Stack<>` is almost always (always?) what one would want to use.

In short (right) - you're getting the error because the type you've said to *use* (via that `using`) doesn't accept types.  It just handles objects.